# Issues with HTTPS Redirection in Dspace 7.6.1, Tomcat 9, and Nginx on Windows 10

Tags: windows, nginx, tomcat, https, dspace

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently facing challenges while setting up HTTPS access for my Dspace 7.6.1 instance, using Tomcat 9 and Nginx as a reverse proxy on a Windows 10 server. This marks my initial Dspace installation, and everything proceeded smoothly. I can access the platform locally through "localhost:4000". However, upon configuring Nginx and attempting external access, a redirection occurs, leading to a 500 error page after 2 seconds.

**Nginx Configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name fevasf-repositorio.ddns.net;
    rewrite ^ https://fevasf-repositorio.ddns.net permanent;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name fevasf-repositorio.ddns.net;

    ssl_certificate C:/nginx-1.25.3/cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key C:/nginx-1.25.3/cert/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /server {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/server;
    }
}
```

**"config.prod.yml" Configuration:**

```
ui:
  ssl: false
  host: localhost
  port: 4000
  nameSpace: /
  rateLimiter:
    windowMs: 60000
    max: 500
  useProxies: true

rest:
  ssl: false
  host: localhost
  port: 8080
  nameSpace: /server
```

**"local.cfg" Configuration:**

```
space.server.url = http://localhost:8080/server
dspace.ui.url = http://localhost:4000
```

**"server.xml" Configuration for Tomcat:**

```
<Connector port="8080"
           minSpareThreads="25"
           enableLookups="false"
           redirectPort="8443"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

**Nginx Log Error:**

```
2023/12/08 13:30:18 [error] 5856#5432: *394 connect() failed (10061: Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.241.215.42, server: fevasf-repositorio.ddns.net, request: "GET /autodiscover/autodiscover.json?@zdi/Powershell HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/autodiscover/autodiscover.json?@zdi/Powershell", host: "189.41.79.255"
```

I've experimented with various configurations, but none have proven successful. Could someone from the community assist me in troubleshooting? I've been grappling with this for a week now. Thank you in advance,